# Set Operation $D = (A \times B) - (B \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to find
$$
D = (A \times B) - (B \times C)
$$
where
$$
A = \{x.y,z\}, \ B = \{1,2\}, \ C = \{x,z\} 
$$
So far I have computed
$$
A \times B = \{(x,1), (x,2), (y,1),(y,2),(z,1),(z,2)\} 
$$
and
$$
B \times C = \{(1,x),(1,z),(2,x),(2,z)\} 
$$
Hence
$$
D = \{(x,1), (x,2), (y,1),(y,2),(z,1),(z,2)\} - \{(1,x),(1,z),(2,x),(2,z)\}
$$
This is where I am stuck because cartesian product order matters. The answer is
$$
D = \{(x,1), (x,2), (y,1),(y,2),(z,1),(z,2)\} 
$$
and I have no idea why. Is difference sets when set doesn't share something together like example $\{1,2,3\} - \{2,3,4\} = \{1\}$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Notice that the answer you gave is $D=A\times B$. This is because $A \times B$ and $B \times C$ are disjoint, whence you will not find elements in $B \times C$ in $A \times B$ to *delete* while computing $D$.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that for two sets $P$ and $Q$

 $P-Q=$ set of all those elements which are in $P$ but not in $Q$. 
In your case, $D$ is the set of elements which are in $A\times B$ but not in $B\times C$. 
Now, consider $(x, 1)\in A\times B$, clearly $(x, 1)\notin B\times C$, hence $(x,1) \in D$. 
Likewise, show that $D = \{(x,1), (x,2), (y,1),(y,2),(z,1),(z,2)\}$

Comment: so difference sets are always disjoint? 

for my example why is it {1} because the other set doesn't have 1. Right?

Comment: @EM4: Disjoint? No! Two sets $P$ and $Q$ are disjoint if they have nothing in common. In your example: clearly $2,3$ are common between the sets $P=\{1,2,3\} $ and $Q=\{2,3,4\}$. $P-Q={1}$ because $1\in P$ but $1\notin Q$. To understand this: draw a rectangle and call it $P$ and then draw a circle inside $P$ and call it $Q$ then $P-Q$ will represent the points outside the circle but inside the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Because no element of $B \times C$ is an element of $A \times B$, the set $D$ is just $A \times B$. Remember: $X - Y = \{ x \in X : x \notin Y \}$ so if every element of $X$ is not an element of $Y$ then $x \notin Y$ is always satisfied so $X - Y = \{x \in X\} = X$.